# Why does nginx always close the connection when I use "return 444", even if there are matching location blocks?

Tags: nginx, configuration

According to my understand of [how nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), the following nginx configuration should lead to all requests matching the prefix location `/`, and thus be served an `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` response redirecting to the https version of the site.

```
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

      location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
    
    return 444;
  }
```

However, that is not what happens:

```
$ curl localhost
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

nginx seems to favor returning 444 (which closes the connection) above responding with the expected redirect.

Obviously this specific example is easily solved by removing the `return 444` statement, but my real life config files are dynamically generated with zero or more location blocks, and I'd prefer having the final "catch-all" `return 444` to prevent nginx from serving its built-in welcome page. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` appearing in a `server` block but not within any `location` is always processed before any `location` blocks are even looked at, in the [phase](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE.

You need to add this to a `location` block which matches anything not matched by your other `location` blocks. So all of your `server` blocks should have *one* or more `location` blocks, not zero or more.